# Can I select text by mouse from a number of delegates in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Lets imaging project for desktop which contains only one QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    ListModel {
        id: myModel

        ListElement {
            color: "red"
            text: "some interesting information"
        }
        ListElement {
            color: "blue"
            text: "not so interesting information"
        }
        ListElement {
            color: "green"
            text: "and some more information"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        interactive: false

        model: myModel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 30
            color: model.color
            TextEdit {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: model.text
                selectByMouse: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the `selectByMouse` property of `TextEdit` set to true I can select text in it. But how can I select text in multiple delegates at the same time? In multiple TextEdits? Is it even possible?

Comment: Having multiple distinct text-edits with an active selection concurrently violates a fairly strong user-interface concept - although it is possible as the answer below states. I wonder if you really want to have the list delegates be multi-selectable (e.g., track their selection state and change the colour of your Rectangle) independent of the text-selection?

Comment: @JamesTurner This is a necessity as the standard `Text` and `Label` elements don't support selection. If you want selectable text you need to use `TextEdit` with disabled editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other answers seem incomplete or don't answer what I believe VALOD9 was asking: "can you select text across multiple delegates as though their TextEdits are one element?"

This is not inherently possible, but can be crafted in QML with a lot of manual tracking of mouse presses and movement.

It could be accomplished by placing MouseArea over your ListView and delegates that each contain DropAreas. To track your text selection clicks/drags across your delegates, you could use an invisible MouseArea.drag.target that triggers the delegate DropAreas' onEntered and onPositionChanged events. Based on all this data, you can use TextEdit.positionAt() with your mouse coordinate results to get where your selections start and end, and use TextEdit.select() to programmatically select the text in each delegate. Since you are programmatically selecting text, your TextEdits would need to have selectByMouse: false.

You will need to store any necessary selection data in your model since you shouldn't store state in delegates in case they are removed from the ListView from automatic caching. You would then use this data to recreate the selection when they are re-loaded from cache using Component.OnCompleted. To do selection operations like copy, you could iterate over your model and pick up the saved selection data (especially if you save the selected text to the model using TextEdit.selectedText).

This would allow many TextEdit-based delegates to act as though they are one when selecting text across any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `persistentSelection` to true and each of your `TextEdit` will keep the text selected (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#persistentSelection-prop)